# Looking for the name of a show like Yu-Gi Oh but american-made and not anime

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm looking for a show that I've watched a long time ago when I was young. It's basically between 2006 and 2010. It tells the story of group of teenagers who are summoning monsters with their cards using the *Yu-Gi-Oh!* Armband.

I remember entering in a blue locked room and fighting against each other while everyone's watching them in like a Card fight Club. Basically It's like *Yu-Gi-Oh!* but not an anime, it's american show.

Comment: Hm. Check these shows: Redakai Conquer the Kairu and 

Bakugan.  It is not good enough for a full blown answer but they both fit what little details you gave.  There is also YuGiOh 5ds which also played at the same time. I hope this helps, if you have more data for us, edit your question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_5D%27s

Comment: How do you know it was not made in japan? 3D does not disqualify in and of itself, and the vast majority of animated shows (**especially** ones with card monster summoning) would have been Japanese. Some reference for the art style or reasoning of this would certainly help narrow the selection down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the name, after 2 years and 6 months: it's [*"Chaotic"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotic_(TV_series)), an American series based on a Dutch card game.

All the episodes can be seen on [*Chaotic*'s YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPdGCLOuKv_74yFawt2oehw/videos).